# How can I publish my restful webservice to internet?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish-4

I don't have much knowledge about webservices.

Now developing a server side code with **Restful** webservices. Also deployed my server side application in **Glassfish 4**.

My webservice is doing its work. I checked by giving the below url in my local machine.

eg: `http://localhost:8080/server/rest/v1/getData`

It give my expected result.

But how can I access my webservice from `internet` (I want to access from a mobile or from computer placed somewhere)?

What are the steps i have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need an Internet connection with static ip (if you are using dynamic ip it will change with every reconnection) so that you can access the application from outside by using **your-static-ip:8080** or buy a droplet from digital ocean or amazon or any other hosting providers so that you can host you application by configuring your glassfish in it.

Comment: Thanks Jovin . Once I have my static IP. What are the steps I need to follow?

Comment: For accessing using ip address, no additional configuration is needed, if you are behind any firewall you may have to open the port for public access. For accessing using domain name you have to set up a web-server with proxy passing enabled. this link may be helpful for the initial setup http://dasunhegoda.com/apache-mod_proxy-as-a-reverse-proxy/778/